# Google place INVALID_REQUEST while sending request to get next page results

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I've faced with problem in iOS application.

I have to get all 60 Google places.
I created loop for sending request and parsing the results.
In this loop I created URL like this:

```
if (nextPageToken != nil && ![nextPageToken isEqualToString:@""])
    pageToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&pagetoken=%@", nextPageToken];

NSString *webStringURL = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?sensor=true&key=%@&location=%@&radius=%@%@", urlString, apiKey, location, radius, pageToken] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
```

Result link for first 20 objects:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?sensor=true&key=YOUR_KEY4&location=50.907654,34.823147&radius=50000&language=ru

It returns the results with no problem. So it's ok.

Result link for the next 20 objects like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?sensor=true&key=YOUR_KEY&location=50.907654,34.823147&radius=50000&pagetoken=ClREAAAA0zIx19jIHXfj0d4vjuIzshv9FTRi9l-ULIAovq5B9Ls0W_vzQFtL6rHVLfoJW4ICpIJlIG3QNRdfayfWp-4L1EjxDklb_kLBquJWX4_jSkgSEMKa1VgBGNQD3jCzW12OrOwaFExWU5GvZXgmKilw8ecaNzMhrucW

But in this case application receives status "INVALID_REQUEST". If I open this link in browser everything is OK. Google returns me the results.

Could you help me what's wrong? I spent a lot of time but I couldn't figure out what I did wrong.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Just added loop where sent requests (with some delay) till get the results. And it took 5min 21sec to get all results. As for me it took much time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchPaging

> There is a short delay between when a next_page_token is issued, and
>   when it will become valid. Requesting the next page before it is
>   available will return an INVALID_REQUEST response. Retrying the
>   request with the same next_page_token will return the next page of
>   results.

Try adding a one (or more) second delay between your requests.

Comment: I tried to use delay between requests. But as I found it was approximately 4-5 minutes. I don't know why so long.

If I open this link in browser it works.

But if I use this link in iOS application it returns "INVALID_REQUEST". And this link starts returns results in 4-5 minutes.

It's weird...

Comment: @Igor Me too! Why do Google set to 4-5 minutes! It's unacceptable! Tell me if you have found the solution.

Comment: @ZhipengYANG frankly speaking I don't remember how I solve this issue. It was some years ago :).

Comment: @Igor Finally I created a list that contains every failed URL, then request again after normal requests have done. Thanks still.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var WAIT_TIME = 2000;
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, WAIT_TIME));
```